# iOS app launching lifecycle changed in uistoryboard

Tags: ios

[image]

`AppDelegate` is basically a delegate of `UIApplication` means it will handle the app level stuff.

But with `storyboard` `appdelegate` does not work as shown in this diagram.

In `storyboard` `viewcontrollers` unarchived and added to `window` and we get the display.

I want to know when `appdelegate` get `registered` as an `delegate of UIApplication` when using `storyboard`? what is the lifecycle when using `uistoryboard`? Is there any visual presentation of this like mentioned above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the code within the `main.m`  file.

```
UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
```

There the last argument is the name of your `AppDelegate` class.  `UIApplicationMain()` will register your `AppDelegate` as the delegate of your application object.

If you are storyboard the creation of window and root view controller within the AppDelegate is not required as you said, instead `UIApplicationMain()` will load the `MainStoryboard` there it will create the window and root view controller.

Comment: you are absolutely correct but why app delegate execute after uistoryboard, when app delegate is defined in main and that is an entry point.

Comment: appdelegate is defined in main() and thats an entry point of app but still app delegate executed after the uistoryboard unarchive its view controller, why app delegate executed in last.

Comment: By app delegate execution did you mean the calling of delegate function? If that is the case FYI. AppDelgate is already created before loading the storyboard file. But the delegate methods will only call after the application set for running. `application: willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` the name itself is explanatory. Now your application is going to finish the launching process.